# Get gridview values from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I want to get the value of a hidden field in a grid view from code-behind, but not to be used in the `_RowDataBound` or any other similar method. Here is my present code (it is a shopping cart scenario):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowPaging="True"
DataKeyNames="ID"
ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="lblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ProductID", "product_details.aspx?id={0}") %>' 
                Text='<%# GetProduct(Eval("ProductID")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Width="35" CssClass="input" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

For the sake of brevity I removed certain fields since they are there only for the display. The Quantity field is there for the user to input a number to add a number of products to his cart. I wish to access the `lblProductID` label in the `_TextChanged` event. In this same event, I tried

`Label lblProductID = (Label)gvShoppingCart.FindControl("lblProductID");`

but it didn't work and returns only a null value. What is the solution?

Comment: How do you know which lblProductID is returned when you have dozens of such control if you are not using the gridView events. I would suggest you use event bubbling. Use RowCommand in place of _TextChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row in your `GridView` there is a `HiddenField` for the ProductID.

You can access the `HiddenField` of a row (in the example below the first row) by using the following code (assuming your `HiddenField` is in the first cell):

```
HiddenField hiddenFieldProductID = 
           (HiddenField)gvShoppingCart.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("lblProductID");

string productID = hiddenFieldProductID.Value

// Do something with the value
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: How can he identify the rowIndex then? Remember he don't wanna use grid events

Comment: @nuux: In the TextChanged event the sender refers to the TextBox control. From there you get to the row Control by accessing ((Control)sender).Parent.Parent.

Comment: @nuux: I've just saw your comment on the question. Sure, RowCommands are also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the HiddenField to a label or a textbox and set the **visible** attribute to false.
I had tried this before and it works.